# MacBook Pro (2015) constantly wakes up during sleep

Tags: mac, sleep, macbook

As the question implies, recently my MacBook Pro (2015) has been overheating when I close the lid.

I first tried debugging the issue by going to the preferences and making sure it wasn't put on the "always awake" mode. When that didn't help, I tried going to [this site](https://medium.com/sfbayhacker/macbook-gets-hot-with-lid-closed-12fc0e7e7016), which told me the primary reason might be a process called DarkPME that's waking up my MacBook Pro up to 4 times every minute. After taking the relevant steps, I was hoping that the issue would resolve itself, but so far no luck. Here's my sample wake reason log for yesterday night (after I had made the relevant changes):

```
2018-08-06 16:01:31.840604-0400 0x74       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.DarkPME (Maintenance)
2018-08-06 16:01:31.840607-0400 0x74       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.DarkPME (Maintenance)
2018-08-06 16:01:32.464340-0400 0x1ebd51   Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2018-08-06 16:02:25.533597-0400 0x74       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.DarkPME (Maintenance)
2018-08-06 16:02:25.533600-0400 0x74       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.DarkPME (Maintenance)
2018-08-06 16:02:26.157490-0400 0x1ec1c5   Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2018-08-06 16:03:19.243847-0400 0x74       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.DarkPME (Maintenance)
2018-08-06 16:03:19.243850-0400 0x74       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.DarkPME (Maintenance)
2018-08-06 16:03:19.869825-0400 0x1ec641   Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2018-08-06 16:04:12.948433-0400 0x74       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.DarkPME (Maintenance)
2018-08-06 16:04:12.948436-0400 0x74       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.DarkPME (Maintenance)
2018-08-06 16:04:13.626345-0400 0x1ecaea   Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2018-08-06 16:05:06.701017-0400 0x74       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.DarkPME (Maintenance)
2018-08-06 16:05:06.701020-0400 0x74       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.DarkPME (Maintenance)
2018-08-06 16:05:07.322234-0400 0x1ecf95   Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
```

As a last ditch effort, I tried looking at my energy preferences by typing `pmset -g`, which gave me this on battery power:

```
System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
 standbydelay         10800
 standby              1
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 powernap             0
 gpuswitch            2
 disksleep            10
 sleep                5 (sleep prevented by fud)
 autopoweroffdelay    0
 hibernatemode        3
 autopoweroff         0
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         5
 tcpkeepalive         1
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1
```

This was yesterday night. Today it says:

```
System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
 standbydelay         10800
 standby              1
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 powernap             0
 gpuswitch            2
 disksleep            10
 sleep                5 (sleep prevented by kextcache)
 autopoweroffdelay    0
 hibernatemode        3
 autopoweroff         0
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         5
 tcpkeepalive         1
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1
```

As you can see, `fud` and `kextcache` are preventing sleep. I have no idea what those processes are and `ps -e | grep fud` reveals nothing.

Not sure what's causing the problem, hopefully someone here can help?

Comment: `fud` is Firmware Update Deamon, I don't think it need to be interrupted

Comment: After checking again, it says "sleep prevented by coreaudiod, fud, kextcache". Should I be concerned about some sort of malware that may be affecting it?

Comment: I changed the .plist files according to the answer on the Apple thread you'd posted. The problem is still the same.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, with the same log entries.I think "preventing sleep" is more a "hang on a tick, let me finish X before sleeping" than the thing that's waking it from sleep. My "preventing" varies. Also, I recently damaged one of the usb-c ports, but Im kinda certain I had this problem before then. But.. do y ou have any non-working ports, etc?